# Using realloc to dynamically grow array of structs causes heap corruption

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to read structured data from a txt file and store it into a struct. Since I don't know how many entries this file will have, I have to dynamically grow an array of structs. I've tried doing that with **realloc**, as per the following code sample:

```
#define BUFFER 200
#define ENTRY_MAX 10 // default number of entries

typedef struct data_storage {
    // store data in this struct
}data_storage;

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    data_storage *data;

    char arr[10*BUFFER];
    char *token; // some data
    const char s[2] = ";"; // this is the data separator in txt file
    char *token_array[ENTRY_MAX];
    int i = 0; // iterator
    int number_of_entries = 1; // starts with at least one entry

    fp = fopen("sample_file.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Impossible to open file \n");
        return 1;
    }
    fgets(arr, 1000, fp); // gets a chunk of data from file

    token = strtok(arr, s);
    data = malloc(number_of_entries*sizeof(data_storage));

    while( token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
        token_array[i] = token;
        i++;

        if(i >= ENTRY_MAX){
            /* 

                DO STUFF: uses strcpy to copy entries from token_array to data

            */
            number_of_entries++; // increments number of entries
            data = realloc(data, number_of_entries*sizeof(data_storage));
            i = 0; // proceeds to read next entry
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to use `strtok` to read a default number of fields, and when the number of tokens reaches ENTRY_MAX I know that I've read an entire entry and can allocate memory for one more struct.

But I'm getting a `realloc(): invalid next size:` error, which looks like heap corruption.

Comment: For starters your `fgets(arr, 1000, fp);` could easily exceed BUFFER. Please use BUFFER as the argument, not 1000.

Comment: `token = strtok(arr, s);` - this is your only chance to _use_ the value in the first token. `strtok(NULL, s);` reads the _next_ token.

Comment: You don't show me any code that uses / writes/ reads `data` so I don't see your evidence that it is corrupted.

Comment: One thing you're clearly doing wrong is failing to test the return value from `malloc()` and `realloc()`.  The latter is especially bad, as it leaks as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @GemTaylor actually `arr` size should always be bigger than BUFFER. I've fixed that in the code. The only evidence of heap corruption was the error message when I tried to run the code. Searching here in Stack Overflow, I've found that similar problems were related to heap corruption.

Comment: The sequence using just 1 size `#define BUFFER 200` `char arr[BUFFER];` `fgets(arr, BUFFER, fp);` is entirely valid and correct.Any other sequence risks the reads writing past the end of your buffer, either now, or when the buffer size is changed independent of the buffer size, and causing the sort of corruption you complain of. [aside: some very early compilers have been known to put the 0 terminator outside the dimension when it exactly fits, so `fgets(arr, BUFFER-1, fp);` can often be seen.]

Comment: Review `data_storage *data; ... sizeof(data_storage)`.  Instead of `data = malloc(number_of_entries*sizeof(data_storage));`, try `data = malloc(number_of_entries*sizeof *data_storage);`

Comment: Why do you reallocate only when you reach `ENTRY_MAX`? You initially allocated only one entry. Only one. What does `ENTRY_MAX` have to do with anything?

Comment: You start with array size of 1 and then exceed bounds before you call realloc

Comment: @M.M yeah! That solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation of `realloc`, if it fails it returns `NULL`. As a result `data = realloc(data,...)` can cause a corruption of the pointer should the function fail. This could lead to ask sorts of issues in the posted code